# makeindex: sorting "7B" as a number

Tags: biblatex, indexing, imakeidx, splitbib

The following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
A\index{7B} simple\index{5} example \index{9} showing\index{7} the problem
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Produces this index:

[image]

I would like "7B" to be listed between 7 and 9. I know that this could be achieved by simply using `\index{7@7B}`, but unfortunately I cannot use this approach (what I have in fact is `\footcite[7B]{ref}`, see below for a more real minimal example)

Is there a general way to solve this problem, by somehow telling `makeindex' to interpret a letter after a number in the way I want?

P.S: My real source is something similar to this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=oscola,indexing=cite]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}

\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}
\indexsetup{noclearpage}
\DeclareIndexAssociation{leg}{tableg}

\makeindex[name=tableg,%
title={Table of Legislation},%
options=-s oscola -c -l,%
columns=1]

\begin{document}

A\footcite[5]{sale} minimal \footcite[7]{sale} 
example\footcite[7B]{sale} showing\footcite[9]{sale} 
the problem. 

\printindex[tableg]
\end{document}
```

and in refs.bib I have:

```
@legislation{sale,
title = {Sale of Goods Act},
date = {1979},
keywords = {leg,en},
entrysubtype = {primary},
pagination = {section}, 
tabulate = {tableg}
}
```

This produces:

[image]

Comment: you might try "72" as a sort field.  the makeindex sort is straight ascii, not numeric by value, so "72" would be sorted between "7" and "9".

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how to apply a sort field to my case. As you can see, the problem occurs at the second level of the index, which comes from the optional argument of the `\footcite` command. This is why I'm asking for a more general solution.

Comment: i have an idea, but i don't have biblatex available.  could you please insert your bibliography data into the example so i can try it out?

Comment: I am not really sure how this example can be built without biblatex... thanks for your concern though. I guess my best shot is to create a customized `footcite` command for the problematic cases, I'll try to think about it.

Comment: okay.  my idea was to try putting a space after each digit, to force it to an ascii sort.  putting this into the current context, that would be `\footcite[5 ]{sale}`.  that might not work, maybe even break spectacularly, but it wouldn't take long to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my very particular case (in which the OSCOLA BibLaTeX style is used) the problem could be solved by changing

```
\footcite[7B]{sale}
```

to

```
\DNI\footcite[7B]{sale}
\index[tableg]{Sale of Goods Act1979@\citeinindex {sale}!8@ s 7B}
```

(the `\DNI` command inhibits the citation, which is later introduced manually through the `\index` command; by the way, this appears in the BL-OSCOLA style documentation, but the example there has an extra blank, and this is why at first I couldn't make this solution work)

In any case, it would be nice to find a general solution for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

A general solution would involve building a regular expression to treat the index item as a set of fields, like a phone number or DOI or IP address (or, indeed, even a postal address), so that V64 comes before V128.

Where would such a solution be situated in the toolchain? Regexes can be used in `makeindex`'s index style file (.ist) by its `sort_rule` directive; regexes are available in expl3; and probably in lua code too.

But Xindy already knows how to do this (in its `/texmf-dist/xindy/modules/base/numeric-sort.xdy` module).

So let's see what a xindy solution would look like.

**A**

Plugging `x\index{V64}x\index{V128}` and a few other index entries into a test file gives us this (latex needs to run with shell-escape, so that xindy can create its work files):

[image: manual 1]

So far, so good: `2` comes before `12`, and so on.

Plugging in section numbers, like `\index[s]{s 7B}`, for a separate index *s* gives:

[image: manual 2]

Also good. (The style and layout, from `xm-statute.xdy` style file, is just for example.)

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{xm-statute.xdy}
(markup-locclass-list :open ": ")
(define-letter-group "Notes" :prefixes ("~b") :before "default")
(merge-rule "Note" "~b") 
(markup-letter-group 
           :open-head "~n {\setlength{\fboxsep}{5pt}\rmfamily\itshape\large\colorbox{yellow!20}{\textcolor{green!40!blue}{\hbox to \dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep{
        \hfill " ; space is needed
           :close-head "\hfill}}~n}}"
       :group "Notes")
(markup-letter-group 
           :open-head "~n {\setlength{\fboxsep}{5pt}\sffamily\bfseries\large\colorbox{blue!30}{\textcolor{yellow!90!red!5}{\hbox to \dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep{
        \hfill " ; space is needed
           :close-head "\hfill}}\nopagebreak\vspace{2mm}}}"
           )

(markup-locclass-list :open "\dotfill" :sep "")

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{xm-generic.xdy}
(markup-letter-group 
           :open-head "~n {\fbox{\textcolor{red!65}{"
           :close-head "\hfill}}\nopagebreak\vspace{2mm}}"
           )

(markup-locclass-list :open "\dotfill" :sep "")

\end{filecontents*}




\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}

\usepackage[hyperindex=false,colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=Xindy--manual: general,
program=texindy,
options=
        -M xm-generic.xdy 
        -C utf8
        ,
columnseprule,
]
\makeindex[name=s,title=Statutes,
program=truexindy,
options=
        -L korean
        -M texindy.xdy
        -M numeric-sort.xdy
        -M xm-statute.xdy 
        -C utf8
        ,
columnseprule,
]

\begin{document}

x\index{aardvark}
x\index[s]{Note!xindy!manual}

\newpage
x\index{10.2.250.1}
x\index{10.12.9.12}
x\index{60.12.251.12}
x\index{10.2.250.1}
x\index{128.12.250.12}
x\index{128.1.250.2}
x\index{V64}x\index{V128}
x\index[s]{s 7}x\index[s]{s 7B}x\index[s]{s 50}x\index[s]{s 5}x\index[s]{s 3(2)(a)}
x\index[s]{SOGA!s 7}x\index[s]{SOGA!s 7B}x\index[s]{SOGA!s 50}x\index[s]{SOGA!s 5}x\index[s]{SOGA!s 3(2)(a)}
x\index{zebra}
x\index{index!xindy!manual}
x\index[s]{index!name!s}
End.


\printindex
\printindex[s]

\end{document}
```

**B**

Adding in `oscola` gives a general (i.e., un-named) index of:

[image: oscola 1]

Everything is holding together.

The separate `legislation` index, after the first (lua)latex run, gives:

[image: oscola 2 pre-biber]

So the bib information is getting through.

Running biber and then latex again fills out the data:

[image: oscola 2 post-biber]

Everything looks to be sorted. ( ;) )

MWE

```
%==========================================
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@legislation{sale,
title = {Sale of Goods Act},
date = {1979},
keywords = {leg,en},
entrysubtype = {primary},
pagination = {section}, 
%tabulate = {tableg}
}
\end{filecontents*}


%==========================================
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{oscola-dev.xdy}
(markup-locclass-list :open ": ")
(define-letter-group "Notes" :prefixes ("~b") :before "default")
(merge-rule "Note" "~b") 
(markup-letter-group 
           :open-head "~n {\setlength{\fboxsep}{5pt}\rmfamily\itshape\large\colorbox{yellow!20}{\textcolor{green!40!blue}{\hbox to \dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep{
        \hfill " ; space is needed
           :close-head "\hfill}}~n}}"
       :group "Notes")
(markup-letter-group 
           :open-head "~n {\setlength{\fboxsep}{5pt}\sffamily\bfseries\large\hbox to \dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep{
        \hfill " ; space is needed
           :close-head "\hfill}}\nopagebreak\vspace{2mm}"
           )

(markup-locclass-list :open "\dotfill" :sep "")

\end{filecontents*}

%==========================================
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{xm-generic.xdy}
(markup-letter-group 
           :open-head "~n {\fbox{\textcolor{red!65}{"
           :close-head "\hfill}}\nopagebreak\vspace{2mm}}"
           )

(markup-locclass-list :open "\dotfill" :sep "")

\end{filecontents*}




%==========================================
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=oscola,indexing=cite]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}


\usepackage[hyperindex=false,colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=Xindy--oscola-dev: general,
program=texindy,
options=
        -M xm-generic.xdy 
        -C utf8
        ,
columnseprule,
]
\makeindex[name=legislation,title=Table of Statutes,
program=texindy,
options=
        -M oscola-dev.xdy 
        -C utf8
        ,
columns=1,
]
\DeclareIndexAssociation{enprimleg}{legislation}


\begin{document}
A\footcites[5]{sale}[21C]{sale} minimal \footcite[7]{sale} x\footcite[21]{sale}
example%\footcite[7B]{sale} 
%\DNI
\footcite[7B]{sale}
showing\footcite[9]{sale} 
the problem.\footcite[3(2)(a)]{sale} 

x\index{aardvark}
x\index[legislation]{Note!xindy!oscola-dev}

\newpage
x\index{10.2.250.1}
x\index{10.12.9.12}
x\index{60.12.251.12}
x\index{10.2.250.1}
x\index{128.12.250.12}
x\index{128.1.250.2}
x\index{V64}x\index{V128}

x\index{zebra}
x\index{index!xindy!oscola-dev}
\index[legislation]{Test entry}
\index[legislation]{SOGA|see{\citeinindex{sale}}}
x\footcites[5]{sale}[21C]{sale} 
\index[legislation]{index!name!legislation}
End.


\printindex
\printindex[legislation]

\end{document}
```

**C**

Now, shifting into production mode, and a more sober garb for our style, our general index becomes, rather nattily:

[image: prod general index]

and the legislation:

[image: prod statute index]

But now we have a different problem: the `legislation.ind` file is produced by `\printindex[legislation]` at the end of the `.tex` file, when all the information is known.

We need to pick up the `.ind` file at the beginning of the next run, but it is just data, with default index name, fonts and layout applied:

[image: prod leg no format]

So we need to apply something like bl-oscola's `\printindexearly` command, to pick up all that formatting.

And to print in the expected location, too, near the front of the document.

Luckily, bl-oscola's maintainer, as the signature of excellence, has put in all the hard work, thinking, designing, implementing (and I do mean, hard); and all we have to do, as a result,  is to change one line of code in one macro, from `\@input@{\jobname-#1.ind}` to `\@input@{#1.ind}`, and all the formatting flows through to give:

[image: prod leg formatted]

So the toolchain becomes: latex with shell-escape, biber, latexSE, latexSE, comment out `\printindex[legislation]` at the end of the document (because we don't need two ToS), and one last latexSE.

MWE

```
%==========================================
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@legislation{sale,
title = {Sale of Goods Act},
date = {1979},
keywords = {leg,en},
entrysubtype = {primary},
pagination = {section}, 
}
\end{filecontents*}


%==========================================
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{oscola.xdy}

(markup-locclass-list :open "\dotfill" :sep "")

\end{filecontents*}

%==========================================
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{xm-generic.xdy}
(markup-locclass-list :open "\dotfill" :sep "")
\end{filecontents*}



%==========================================
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=oscola,indexing=cite]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}


\usepackage[hyperindex=false,colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=General Index,
program=texindy,
options=
        -M xm-generic.xdy 
        -C utf8
        ,
columnseprule,
]
\makeindex[name=legislation,title=Table of Statutes,
program=texindy,
options=
        -M oscola.xdy 
        -C utf8
        ,
columns=1,
]
\DeclareIndexAssociation{enprimleg}{legislation}



\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\bbx@putimindextosplit}[1]{%
  \let\imki@indexname\indexname
  \@nameuse{imki@set@#1}%
  \ifimki@nonewpage\else
    \imki@clearpage
  \fi
  \ifKV@imki@intoc
   \def\imki@maybeaddtotoc{\@nameuse{phantomsection}%
     \addcontentsline{toc}{\imki@toclevel}{\imki@title}}%
  \else
   \def\imki@maybeaddtotoc{}%
  \fi
  \ifx\imki@title\imki@check@indexname\else
    \def\indexname{\imki@title}%
  \fi
%  \@input@{\jobname-#1.ind}
  \@input@{#1.ind}
  \let\indexname\imki@indexname
}
\makeatother




\begin{document}
\printindexearly[legislation]
\newpage

A\footcites[5]{sale}[21C]{sale} minimal \footcite[7]{sale} x\footcite[21]{sale}
example\footcite[7B]{sale}
showing\footcite[9]{sale} 
the problem.\footcite[3(2)(a)]{sale} 

x\index{aardvark}

\newpage
x\index{10.2.250.1}
x\index{10.12.9.12}
x\index{60.12.251.12}
x\index{10.2.250.1}
x\index{128.12.250.12}
x\index{128.1.250.2}
x\index{V64}x\index{V128}

x\index{zebra}
x\index{index!xindy!oscola}
\index[legislation]{SOGA|see{\citeinindex{sale}}}
x\footcites[5]{sale}[21C]{sale} 
End.


\printindex
\printindex[legislation] % comment out when not needed

\end{document}
```